# Issues FB.api('/me/likes/

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have problem with fb api.

```
FB.api('/me/likes/pageid',function(response) {
console.log(response.data); 
});
```

i have

```
Object
category: "Entertainment"
created_time: "2012-09-17T16:56:56+0000"
id: "pageid"
name: "site.com"
```

but on one computer i have **undefined Object { data=[0]}**

I logged in on both in facebook. any ideas?

in FF i have

```
An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify a valid access_token

This is the right way to do that

```
FB.api('/me/likes/pageid', {access_token: "YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN"}, function(response) {
   console.log(response.data); 
});
```

You have to add "user_likes" to the scope of your app to retrieve the result

Comment: Why would FB insist on making a user accept permissions for a  page to determine if that user has liked the page or not? Seems somewhat draconian and has certainly changed in the last year.